# C# ASP.NET кэширование файлов-сертификатов их чтение при генерации билетов формата pkpass

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Всем привет.

**Предыстория:**

Работаю над проектом веб-приложения на ASP.NET. Через веб-приложение осуществляется продажа билетов и естественно, получить билеты можно как в PDF так и в pkpass форматах. 
При генерации билетов pkpass к билету необходимо прикрепить ключ и сертификат (это 2 файла) и отправить на валидацию в Apple. Собственно, этим занимается NuGet библиотека. 
**Вот какая проблема у меня возникла:**

Долго описывать причину, но суть в том, что нам пришлось перейти на библиотеку [PassSharp](https://github.com/daxko/PassSharp/blob/master/readme.md), в следствии чего переписать весь код запроса. 
Используя новую библиотеку, при большой нагрузке на сайт часть pkpass-ов перестала валидироваться (от 0 до 10-ти штук в день +/-) и на яблочных устройствах они не открываются. **Причина**: несколько раз в день 2 пользователя завершают оплату в одну и ту же секунду и второй поток не может получить доступ к файлу. Получаем IOException. 
Пример кода:

```
    Набрали объект pass (не важно для задачи), далее:
    using (var myStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
        string fileNamePK = String.Format(часть алгоритма генерации имени+ @"{0}.pkpass", часть алгоритма генерации имени; //не спрашивайте
//Проблема вот здесь:
        byte[] appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(currDir + "//" + appleCert);
        byte[] appleCertKey = File.ReadAllBytes(currDir + "//" + appleKey);

        PassWriter.WriteToStream(pass, myStream,
                new X509Certificate2(appleCert),
                new X509Certificate2(appleCertKey,appleCertPass,  X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable));
        FileStream file = new FileStream(FileNamePath + "\\" + fileNamePK, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        myStream.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
        myStream.Close();
        ResultListPass += fileNamePK + ";";
        }
```

А казлось бы, как невелик шанс, что такое произойдет...

Все примеры, которые нахожу предлагают делать что-то вроде этого:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
StreamReader fsr = new StreamReader(fs);
byteArrey = fsr.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(fsr.ReadToEnd());
```

Но X509Certificate2 принимает массив байтов, а подобные методы нацелены на чтение текстовой информации и как я не пытался это обойти (к примеру вот так: CurrentEncoding.GetBytes) - без результатоно. Массив байт после такой операции получается не корректным. Ради проверки после byteArrey я даже дописал строку var test = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); - массивы байт отличаются.
Идеальным вариантом было бы кэширвать эти файлы на уровне приложения и получать их из памяти, но как это сделать я не знаю...
Видмо это нужно делать на уровне IIS, но опять таки - не знаю как. А если разберусь - как получить к ним доступ?
Помогите пожалуйста, кто чем может...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поигравшись с библиотекой **PassSharp** какое-то время и испробовав различные варианты (в т.ч. и приведенные выше) сделали вывод, что дело не в реализации, а в самой библиотеке так как симптомы сохранялись независимо от моих действий. Видимо она не подходит для столь нагруженного приложения.

Далее - я вернулся к библиотеке **dotnet-passbook** и попытался разобраться по какой причине она перестала работать. После довольно детального разбора я увидел, что в установленной библиотеке отсутствует часть методов, которые есть в GitHub-репозитории библиотеки. Так как переустановка библиотеки не решала проблему я переопределил классы PassGenerator и PassGeneratorRequest внутри нашего приложения используя код из GitHub благодаря чему решение работает по сей день.

Answer (score 0):

Если файлы небольшие, то можно использовать InMemoryCache.

```
byte[] 
    appleCert,
    appleCertKey;

MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
DateTime cacheExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);

string 
    appleCertCacheKey = "appleCert",
    appleCertKeyCacheKey = "appleCertKey";

if (cache.Contains(appleCertCacheKey) && cache.Contains(appleCertKeyCacheKey))
{
    appleCert = cache.Get(appleCertCacheKey) as byte[];
    appleCertKey = cache.Get(appleCertKeyCacheKey) as byte[];
}
else
{
    appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(currDir + "//" + appleCert);
    appleCertKey = File.ReadAllBytes(currDir + "//" + appleKey);

    cache.Add(appleCertCacheKey, appleCert, cacheExpiration);
    cache.Add(appleCertKeyCacheKey, appleCertKey, cacheExpiration);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень интересный вариант. Сегодня протестирую, но хочу так же уточнить, при загрузки в МемориКеш - эти файлы будут доступны и в других сессиях? Это основная задача

Comment: Да, они хранятся в оперативной памяти отдельно от запросов

Comment: Наконец снова сюда добрался :) У меня по какой-то причине в System.Runtime нет пространства имен Caching, которое содержит MemoryCache)) Как такое может быть?) Гуглил-гуглил - без толку

Comment: В обозревателе решений пкм на "ссылки" ->Добавить ссылку ->  Сборки -> ищите System.Runtime.Caching

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но после тщательного логирования с большой долей вероятности выяснилось, что проблема не в чтении файлов =( Вероятнее всего, что проблема с самой библиотекой или на шаге записи myStream.WriteTo(file);. Покопавшись в библиотеке оказалось, что в ней есть метод, который сам пишет файлы, без лишних файлстримов (изначально делалось наспех так как на старой библиотеке все резко поломалось). После теста отпишусь дополнительно.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать [lock](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) на проблемной части кода

```
static object globalObject = new Object();
...
lock (globalObject)
{ /*тут открытие и чтение из файла*/ }
```

или прочтите байты и закешируйте их в статическую переменную, если они не меняются.